# How to allow only process page to work if it was accessed from form?

Tags: php, isset

On the form page I am using:

```
<input type="hidden" value="3490" name="test">
```

Then on the process page i am doing this to check:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['test']) ) {
    echo "error";
} 
?>
```

For some reason it doesn't work.  When i go to process page the page is printing no errors.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://codepad.org/ClJ9vDIv

Comment: Maybe you want if (! isset($_POST['test']) ) . Note the ! (NOT)

Comment: is the FORM TYPE set to POST?

Comment: @jaredfarrish it worked! thanks.  write as an answer so i can accept as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to reverse the boolean result of `isset()` to detect if it's empty:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['test']) ) {
    echo "error";
} 
?>
```

http://codepad.org/ClJ9vDIv

Note the `!`, which in this case turns the `false` outcome (no/false, it isn't set) into a `true` outcome (yes/true, it isn't set).